# How to return false condition from datatables method?

Tags: c#, datatable, boolean

i want to ask is there any way to get false condition from returning data? i want to get the false condition from this readFolder function if the size > 4000

```
public DataTable readFolder(string path, string ext){
        MBer = new Models.MBerkas();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow dr;

        //Initialize Directory path
        string ax = path;

        string[] s1 = Directory.GetFiles(ax, "*."+ext+"*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
       
        //File Name, File Type, File size, create date
        for (int i = 0; i <= s1.Length - 1; i++)
        {
           
                dt = MBer.setHeader;
            

            FileInfo f = new FileInfo(s1[i]);
            FileSystemInfo f1 = new FileInfo(s1[i]);

            double size = Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(f.Length / 1024), 0);

            if (size <= 4000)
            {
                int lineCount = MBer.getLineCount(s1[i]);

                dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr = MBer.getRowTable(dr, f1, f, lineCount);

                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
            else {
                MessageBox.Show("" + f1.Name + " size too large.");
                return false;
            }
        }            
        return dt;
    }
```

Comment: `public bool TryReadFolder(string path, string ext, out DataTable dataTable)` ill let you research the rest

Comment: If you don't need any specific information, the simplest answer is simply to return `null`..

Answer (score 0):

You can throw an exception from the function or have an `out` parameter which you will check for:

```
public DataTable readFolder(string path, string ext, out bool valid){
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna go a different direction and suggest something more like this:

```cs
public async IAsyncEnumerable<(FileInfo, FileSystemInfo)> readFolder(string path, string ext)
{
    var d = new DirectoryInfo(path);  
    var s1 = d.EnumerateFiles("*."+ext+"*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
       
    foreach(FileInfo fi in s1) //FileInfo inherits from FileSystemInfo! You don't need both.
    {   
        if (fi.Length < 4097024) // 4097024 is the first value n where round(n/1024)>4000
        {
            yield reutrn fi;
        }
        else
        {
            // **LOG** the results, or add to a collection you can check afterwards that was passed as an argument.
            // You could also *break* here, to leave the loop and just stop.
        }
    }
}
```

There's a lot less code here, but it will run a **LOT FASTER** (I'm saving you at least three disk seeks per file!) and be a lot more fault tolerant, and it gives you all the same data. Additionally, the presence of the `Models` namespace suggests MVC, where the `async` feature can create another big performance win.

To explain the magic number which replaced the `size` criteria, this is easy to find by writing [a short program](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EHMnOw), and will further save you some calculation time on each file.

Even if you really want the datatable, I'd **still** write this code instead, and then wrap it in another method that uses this result to create your table.

Comment: `IAsyncEnumerable` over a standard Iterator is a curious choice. There will be no IO completion callbacks here and will tie up a thread just the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can return `bool` or throw an exception for the given condition.